# Use parameters for non-value items in sql statement

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, parameters

I am trying to create a method to read a specific  field from the database.

The compiler is treating the database `tblName` as `@tblName` instead of the parameter I passed to the method. The same happens to the rest of the sql parameters.
It seems to me the compiler is ignoring all the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` statements.

- It seems the SQL query ends up being:

  `SELECT [@colTarget] FROM [@tblName] WHERE [@colRef] = @refValue;`
- instead of something like (example of what I have expected):

  `SELECT [FirstName] FROM [tblUser] WHERE [Email] = 'abc@gmail.com';`

---

This is what I have come out with.

```
public string selectField(string tblName, string colTarget, string colRef, string refValue)
{    
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.AppendLine("SELECT [@colTarget] FROM [@tblName] WHERE [@colRef] = @refValue;");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colTarget", colTarget);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblName", tblName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colRef", colRef);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refValue", "'" + refValue + "'");  

    //open connection and execute query
    //close connection
    //return field value    
}
```

I appreciate if anyone can let me know what went wrong with these codes.

Comment: You can only use parameters for values, not to replace the names of tables or columns.  You'll still have to do string formating or concatenation to create a sql query with dynamic table and column names.

Comment: @juharr I see, you can post your solution, I will gladly accept it. Thanks alot. Have been spending many hours.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answer ;)

Comment: Say hello to my little friend [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). You could validate the parameter values against the [information schema views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) within a stored procedure. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use parameters for values, not to replace the names of tables or columns. You'll still have to do string formating or concatenation to create a sql query with dynamic table and column names.

```
public string selectField(string tblName, string colTarget, string colRef, string refValue)
{    
    string query = string.Format(
        "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = @refValue;",
        colTarget,
        tblName,
        colRef);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@refValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = refValue;  

    //open connection and execute query
    //close connection
    //return field value    
}
```

Also you don't need to put the single quotes around the `refValue` and it's better to avoid `AddWithValue` and instead specify the type of the parameter explicitly.  For that reason you might want to consider also including the type of the `colRef` column as another argument to your method.

Comment: Thank you for your post, do you mind elaborate or give an example what do you mean by `and instead specify the type of the parameter explicitly` ? Thanks once again.

Comment: @user3437460 It's where I used `cmd.Parameters.Add` and passed in `SqlDbType.VarChar` to indicate that the type of the column `colRef` will be varchar.  You could change it to `NVarChar` or whatever you expect it to actually be, or as I mentioned you can pass that information to the method as well.  The `AddWIthValue` is just going to attempt to figure out the type of the parameter from the type of the object value you pass when it creates it and some times it can get it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have one last question. (Sorry for being greedy in asking) Is using `"SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = @refValue;"` where the column becomes dynamic vulnerable to SQL injection? If it does, is it actually a better practice to hard code the column names?

Comment: It really depends on where the table and column names come from.  If they can be entered by a user, then yes this would be vulnerable to sql injection.  So it would be better if the values passed to this method are not entered by a user, but instead values that you hard code, or maybe values you get from inspecting the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters in SQL only work for **values** not identifiers of columns or tables. So in your `select` statement, only the last parameter is a value.

Also specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`. Check this: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@refValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = refValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SQLParameter does not work with tablenames and columns.

You will have to declare the 'tblName' directly in the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by purpose to avoid SQL injection attacks https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection .
Parameters are not expanded inline, so you don't need to quote strings.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to perform those substitutions yourself similar to the following.  Be aware of the potential for SQL injection, though...

```
query.AppendLine(string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE [@colRef] = @refValue;", colTarget, tblName);
```

And did I mention SQL injection?  Also, as an aside... SQL Injection :)

Comment: You also have to do the replacement for `colRef`.

Comment: @dazedandconfused So is it a better practice to just hard code the column names into the sql string query?